# ZendFramework - How to test bandwidth? When visitor open a page to display his upload/download

Tags: php, zend-framework, bandwidth

When i am running the server and visitor is trying to open the page `www.site.com/zf/bandwidth`. How can i display the user his upload/download speed? Which adapter / class can be used.

```
class ZfController extends  Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function bandwidthAction() {
     // show the upload/ download speed of that visitor
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [ProgressBar Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html#zend.file.transfer.introduction.uploadprogress) to measure the bandwith for predefined packages and return it to the user of your website.

Comment: But this is not both? Such as Download and Upload measure. File transfer is upload actually. So you are saying upload and again download the same file to measure it?

Comment: In fact you could measure upload trough `FileTransfer`and download trough some javascript .. (this would be my approach).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not really suitable for this sort of thing. The "speed test" type websites normally use a browser plugin, so you might want to hunt around to see if you can find something off-the-shelf you can use that will likely be written in either Java or Flash.